# KeyError Pandas Dataframe (encoding index)

Tags: python-2.7, indexing, pandas, encoding, keyerror

I'm running the code below. It creates a couple of dataframes that takes a column in another dataframe that has a list of Conference Names, as its index.

```
    df_conf = pd.read_sql("select distinct Conference from publications where year>=1991 and length(conference)>1 order by conference", db)

    for index, row in df_conf.iterrows():
            row[0]=row[0].encode("utf-8")

    df2= pd.DataFrame(index=df_conf['Conference'], columns=['Citation1991','Citation1992'])

    df2 = df2.fillna(0)
    df_if= pd.DataFrame(index=df_conf['Conference'], columns=['IF1994','IF1995'])

    df_if = df_if.fillna(0)

    df_pubs=pd.read_sql("select Conference, Year, count(*) as totalPubs from publications where year>=1991 group by conference, year", db)

    for index, row in df_pubs.iterrows():
        row[0]=row[0].encode("utf-8")

    df_pubs= df_pubs.pivot(index='Conference', columns='Year', values='totalPubs')
    df_pubs.fillna(0)

    for index, row in df2.iterrows():
        df_if.ix[index,'IF1994'] = df2.ix[index,'Citation1992'] / (df_pubs.ix[index,1992]+df_pubs.ix[index,1993])
```

The last line keeps giving me the following error:

```
KeyError: 'Analyse dynamischer Systeme in Medizin, Biologie und \xc3\x96kologie'
```

Not quite sure what I'm doing wrong. I tried encoding the indexes. It won't work. I even tried `.at` still wont' work.

I know it has to do with encoding, as it always stops at indexes with non-ascii characters.

I'm using python 2.7

Comment: Are you sure that it is encoding at all as your for loop looks iffy, could you try `df_conf[0] = df_conf[0].apply(encode, 'utf-8)`

Comment: Actually if you're running pandas 0.15.0 or higher then you should be to do this which is much quicker `df_conf[0] = df_conf[0].str.encode('utf-8')` as this is vectorised

Comment: Well can you try `df_conf[col_name] = df_conf[col_name].str.encode('utf-8')` replace `col_name` with whatever column you want to encode, saying that can you encode your index? Is your index a str? could you try `df_conf.index = df.conf.index.str.encode('utf-8')`

Comment: That worked! thanks! Why didn't the loop work?

Comment: Which worked the index bit or the `df_conf[col_name]` bit? the reason the loop didn't work is because you're iterating over the rows and values but modifying a copy of the data so the orig df is not mutated. To modify the df you should do direct column assignment or use `.loc`, `.iloc` or `.ix`, let me know what worked specifically and I will post an answer along with sample data to explain

Comment: the df_conf[col_name] worked! But I'm guessing even the other one would have worked too!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the problem with this:

```
for index, row in df_conf.iterrows():
    row[0]=row[0].encode("utf-8")
```

is that it may or may not work, I'm surprised it didn't raise a warning.

Besides that it's much quicker to use the vectorised [`str`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/api.html#string-handling) method to [`encode`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.encode.html#pandas.Series.str.encode) the series:

```
df_conf['col_name'] = df_conf['col_name'].str.encode('utf-8')
```

If needed you can also encode the index in a similar fashion:

```
df.index = df.index.str.encode('utf-8')
```

Comment: I tried the last one: `df.index = df.index.str.encode('utf-8')` and got `AttributeError: 'Index' object has no attribute 'str'`

Comment: Hmm. is your index really str dtype? if not then that won't work but originally I thought your index was a str, if not then ignore this code snippet

Comment: It is a str, it's names of conferences. If you notice the key error in the questions, it highlights one of the indexes.

Comment: What version pandas are you using then as this works fine in 0.16.1

Answer (score 0):

It happens in the line in the last part of the code?

```
df_if.ix[index,'IF1994'] = df2.ix[index,'Citation1992'] / (df_pubs.ix[index,1992]+df_pubs.ix[index,1993])
```

if then, try

```
df_if.ix[index,u'IF1994'] = df2.ix[index,u'Citation1992'] / (df_pubs.ix[index,1992]+df_pubs.ix[index,1993])
```

It would work. Dataframe indexing in UTF8 works in strange way even though the script is declared with "# -*- coding:utf8 -*-". Just put "u" in utf8 strings when you use dataframe columns and index with utf8 strings